# Can MDM track my location?

Tags: privacy, geolocation

I have Maas360 on my iPhone, but the app isn't installed it's only listed under MDM. Can it track my location even if I didnt give the app location permissions?

Comment: If you didn’t give it permissions then no. If you gave it permission then theoretically yes

Comment: @Josh never gave the app permission. I did a fresh install but MDM stays on the phone

Comment: So...Are you asking how to remove a MDM?

Comment: @Josh dont think I can without the administrator account on Maas.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn’t give the app location permission then the app **cannot** access your location. If you gave it permission then theoretically yes, it could track you.

From [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207092):

### How to turn Location Services on or off for specific apps

> 1. Go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services.
> 2. Make sure that Location Services is on.
> 3. Scroll down to find the app.
> 4. Tap the app and select an option:
>
>    - Never: Prevents access to Location Services information.
>    - While Using the App: Allows access to Location Services only when the app or one of its features is visible on screen. If an app is set
>        to While Using the App, you might see your status bar turn blue with a
>        message that an app is actively using your location.
>    - Always: Allows access to your location even when the app is in the background.